# Interface and class cast

Tags: java

Trying to cast `printable` to **interface** `Printable`:

```
class Printable2{}
interface Printable {}
class BlackInk {}


class TwistInTaleCasting {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Printable printable = null;
        BlackInk blackInk = new BlackInk();
        printable = (Printable)blackInk;
    }
}
```

Got runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: BlackInk cannot be cast to Printable
    at TwistInTaleCasting.main(TwistInTaleCasting.java:17)
```

Trying to cast `printable` to **class**`Printable2`:

```
class Printable2{}
interface Printable {}
class BlackInk {}


class TwistInTaleCasting {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Printable2 printable = null;
        BlackInk blackInk = new BlackInk();
        printable = (Printable2)blackInk;
    }
}
```

Got error at compile time:

```
Error:(17, 33) java: incompatible types: BlackInk cannot be converted to Printable2
```

Why compiler does not checks **interface** cast and checks **class** cast?